# OpenCV displaying 2 images adjacently in the same window

Tags: image-processing, opencv, roi

I am trying to display 2 images horizontally adjacent to each other in the same window using OpenCV.

I have tried using adjustROI function for this.Image 1 has 1088 pixels width and 2208 pixels height while Image 2 has 1280 pixels width and 2208 pixels height.Please suggest what could be wrong in the code below.All I am getting is an image of size Image2 with content from Image2 as well.

```
Mat img_matches=Mat(2208,2368,imgorig.type());//set size as combination of img1 and img2
img_matches.adjustROI(0,0,0,-1280); 
imgorig.copyTo(img_matches);
img_matches.adjustROI(0,0,1088,1280);
imgorig2.copyTo(img_matches);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**EDIT:** Here's how I'd do what you want to do:

```
Mat left(img_matches, Rect(0, 0, 1088, 2208)); // Copy constructor
imgorig.copyTo(left);
Mat right(img_matches, Rect(1088, 0, 1280, 2208)); // Copy constructor
imgorig2.copyTo(right);
```

The copy constructors create a copy of the `Mat` header that points to the ROI defined by each of the `Rect`s.

Full code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Mat im1 = imread(argv[1]);
    Mat im2 = imread(argv[2]);
    Size sz1 = im1.size();
    Size sz2 = im2.size();
    Mat im3(sz1.height, sz1.width+sz2.width, CV_8UC3);
    Mat left(im3, Rect(0, 0, sz1.width, sz1.height));
    im1.copyTo(left);
    Mat right(im3, Rect(sz1.width, 0, sz2.width, sz2.height));
    im2.copyTo(right);
    imshow("im3", im3);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles with:

```
g++ foo.cpp -o foo.out `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

**EDIT2:**

Here's how it looks with `adjustROI`:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Mat im1 = imread(argv[1]);
    Mat im2 = imread(argv[2]);
    Size sz1 = im1.size();
    Size sz2 = im2.size();
    Mat im3(sz1.height, sz1.width+sz2.width, CV_8UC3);
    // Move right boundary to the left.
    im3.adjustROI(0, 0, 0, -sz2.width);
    im1.copyTo(im3);
    // Move the left boundary to the right, right boundary to the right.
    im3.adjustROI(0, 0, -sz1.width, sz2.width);
    im2.copyTo(im3);
    // restore original ROI.
    im3.adjustROI(0, 0, sz1.width, 0);
    imshow("im3", im3);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

You have to keep track of what the current ROI is, and the syntax for moving the ROI around can be a little un-intuitive.  The result is the same as the first block of code.

Comment: This doesn't work either.I think the first 2 parameters need to be zero in both cases because the height of both images is (almost) same and i just need to place them side by side.

Comment: I've just realized adjustROI behaves slightly differently to what I'm used to (the old C cvSetImageROI).  Check out my updated answer.

Comment: i had tried something similar.The copy constructor is giving a copy of the original matrix,so when I try to print "img_matches" it still is blank.While printing "left" and "right" separately gives those images

Comment: The constructor copies the header of the matrix, not the underlying data.  The underlying data remains shared with the original image.  So when you copyTo left/right, you're actually copying to the original image.  I've just tried it -- it works.  See my updated answer for full code.

Comment: I got bored and tried using `adjustROI`.  Looking at your question, you were very close to finding the solution by yourself.  The only thing you did wrong was forgetting to reset the ROI.

Comment: None of these work. Just make the code a function, pass two images, and you can see it doesn't work. The first method gives a black window, second one just displays only second image.

Answer (score 9):

As the height (rows of Mat) of the images are same, function `hconcat` maybe used to horizontally concatenate two images (Mat) and thus can be used to display them side-by-side in the same window. [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaab5ceee39e0580f879df645a872c6bf7).
It works with both grayscale and color images. The number of color channels in the source matrices must be same.

```
Mat im1, im2; // source images im1 and im2

Mat newImage;
hconcat(im1, im2, newImage);  // <---- place image side by side

imshow("Display side by side", newImage);
waitKey(0);
```

For the sake of completeness, `vconcat` can be similarly used for vertical concatenation.

Comment: with the hconcat the mats need to be of the same dimensions

Comment: @BossShell By dimensions, if you mean color channels (not the dimensions of matrix), then yes, they need to be same (will update answer).
To be explicit: for `hconcat`, the columns of the source mats can be different.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution inspired in @misha's answer.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Mat im1 = imread(argv[1]);
    Mat im2 = imread(argv[2]);
    Size sz1 = im1.size();
    Size sz2 = im2.size();
    Mat im3(sz1.height, sz1.width+sz2.width, CV_8UC3);
    im1.copyTo(im3(Rect(0, 0, sz1.width, sz1.height)));
    im2.copyTo(im3(Rect(sz1.width, 0, sz2.width, sz2.height)));
    imshow("im3", im3);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of using the copy constructor, this solution uses [Mat::operator()(const Rect& roi)](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat%20Mat::operator()(const%20Rect&%20roi)%20const). While both solutions are O(1), this solution seems cleaner.